# Blocking navigation in React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am having an issue with navigation blocking in React.

I use React + Redux with React Router. I have been using the  component in order to prevent navigation from incomplete forms within React. This works fine as long as the navigation is actually within React. What it doesn't block, however, is navigation via URL entry, or clicking on an external hyperlink.

Is there an accepted method in React for handling external hyperlinks and blocking navigation outside of React?

Comment: Hi, Are you handling the "external hyperlinks" through react-router history?

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the reply. The website I am working with currently is in transition between a Django app and moving to React. The topbar (rendered outside the React content area on React apps) has links to Django-based pages as well as other React-Router friendly links. So, the hyperlinks aren't all nice `<Link />` elements. I'm more-or-less looking for a React-based `window.onbeforeunload` to prompt the user before the navigate away from an incomplete form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide any code here, so I'm trying to guess. If I understand you correctly, you are able to manage you internal redirects thought the React app via react-router without any issues.

As per your statement:

> What it doesn't block, however, is navigation via URL entry, or clicking on an external hyperlink.

Let's tackle both questions. First can't prevent a user from going to the navigation bar and enter a new URL, that done by design on the browsers side, it would be bad for the user, and of course invasive!

But regarding your second question about clicking on a link that will send you outside your domain or application, you can do something about it.

You have multiple options here, I will give you three:

### First: Use history.block

You can block or better said, ask the user to acknowledge the transition to another page by using [history.block](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#blocking-transitions)

As an example from the history docs:

```
const unblock = history.block('Are you sure you want to leave this page?')
```

### Second: Use history.push instead of href

Just don't use anchor elements `href`, but rely on the `history` of `react-router`.

You can read more about it here: [react-router/history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md)

But basically you can wire your redirection using the push method from history, which will look something like:

```
onClick() {
    //code to control if you want to redirect or not
    history.push('http://yoururl.com');
}
```

### Third: Use Redirect component with conditional rendering

Then you have other options like for example using conditional rendering combined with Redirect components, but the other approach would be enough to solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I am sorry that I didn't flesh my answer out properly. So, to be succinct, the behavior I am looking for is similar to the oft-abused, `window.window.onbeforeunload()`. It isn't to -stop- the user from leaving in my case, but to give me a little reminder that their form isn't complete. While `window.onbeforeunload` will work, I was wondering if there was something more native to React/integrated with React-Router that would work in this instance. Hopefully I expressed myself a bit better that time!

Comment: Ohhh @koonsies as per you question, you stated you wanted to block the user in some way. If that is the case, Which kind of action do you want to do in that "reminder"? do you want to ask the user if he wants to leave the form? or do you just want to log somewhere that the person left the form without entering some fields?

Comment: Because if that is the case, now you have other options

Comment: BTW, you know that using `onbeforeunload` is not safe in all the browsers, since in most of them if you fire a message there it won't be loaded

Comment: Yup! The default message of "Your changes may not be saved" is fine. It simply to prevent accidental navigation/form clearing after they've made a change to the form.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for Blocking Transitions under the history api for React Router.

As per the example on react router history github page:

You can register a simple prompt message that will be shown to the user before they navigate away from the current page.

`const unblock = history.block('Are you sure you want to leave this page?')`

Detailed info at https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#properties